# How to show a function is $1-1$ and onto?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine if the following function $T: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is one to one and/or onto:

$$T(x,y)=(x^2,y)$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of $1-1$ and onto?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. What point maps to $(1, 0)$? What point maps to $(-1, 0)$?

Answer (score 1):

It's neither.

Since $x^2 \geq 0$, the point $(-1, 0)$ is not in the image. So, $T$ is not surjective.

Since $x^2 = (-x)^2$, the points $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ have the same image $(1, 0)$. So, $T$ is not injective.